# Dynamic start-urls list when crawling with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
class SomewebsiteProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "somewebsite"
    allowed_domains = ["somewebsite.com"]


start_urls = [

]

def parse(self, response):
    items = somewebsiteItem()

    title = response.xpath('//h1[@id="title"]/span/text()').extract()
    sale_price = response.xpath('//span[contains(@id,"ourprice") or contains(@id,"saleprice")]/text()').extract()
    category = response.xpath('//a[@class="a-link-normal a-color-tertiary"]/text()').extract()
    availability = response.xpath('//div[@id="availability"]//text()').extract()
    items['product_name'] = ''.join(title).strip()
    items['product_sale_price'] = ''.join(sale_price).strip()
    items['product_category'] = ','.join(map(lambda x: x.strip(), category)).strip()
    items['product_availability'] = ''.join(availability).strip()
    fo = open("C:\\Users\\user1\PycharmProjects\\test.txt", "w")
    fo.write("%s \n%s \n%s" % (items['product_name'], items['product_sale_price'], self.start_urls))
    fo.close()
    print(items)
    yield items
```

test.py

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
            'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
        })

        process.crawl(SomewebsiteProductSpider)
        process.start()
```

How can I pass a dynamic start_urls list to a "SomewebsiteProductSpiders" object from test.py before launching the crawling process ? Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`process.crawl` accepts optional parameters that are passed to spider's constructor, so you can either populate `start_urls` from spider's `__init__` or use custom `start_requests` procedure. For example

**test.py**

```
...
process.crawl(SomewebsiteProductSpider, url_list=[...])
```

**somespider.py**

```
class SomewebsiteProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.start_urls = kwargs.pop('url_list', [])
        super(SomewebsiteProductSpider, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Maybe it is slightly different question, but when I pass the list of itmes as a string I get each url as a separate letter. Here is a statement form scrapy website "If you were to set the start_urls attribute from the command line, you would have to parse it on your own into a list using something like ast.literal_eval() or json.loads() and then set it as an attribute. Otherwise, you would cause iteration over a start_urls string (a very common python pitfall) resulting in each character being seen as a separate url." How do i set up an attribute?

Comment: I suppose you mean that you pass the list of items as a CLI parameter. Then just pass it as, says, comma-delimited list and split it like `self.start_urls = comma_delimited_string.split(',')`

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid additional kwargs parsing from @mizghun's answer simply by passing start_urls as a parameter.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'quotes'

  def parse(self, response):
    print(response.url)

 process = CrawlerProcess()
 process.crawl(QuotesSpider, start_urls=["http://example.com", "http://example.org"])
 process.start()
```